# Correct usage of offsetof macro

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic, offsetof

I'm trying to work with the `offsetof` macro in the following way:

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short u16;

struct MapBlock
{
  u16 type : 10;
  u8 variant : 3;
  bool isTop : 1;
};

struct MapTile
{
  struct MapBlock top, middle;
  u16 x;
  u8 y;
};

MapTile *tfb(struct MapBlock *block)
{
  if (block->isTop)
    return (MapTile*)block;
  else
    return (MapTile*)((u8*)block - offsetof(struct MapTile, middle));
}
```

and it seems to work with this simple test case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
  {
    map[i][j].x = i;
    map[i][j].y = j;
    map[i][j].top.isTop = true;
    map[i][j].middle.isTop = false;
  }

printf("%p == %p == %p\n",tfb(&map[40][50].top),tfb(&map[40][50].middle),&map[40][50]);
```

Now the real questions:

- is it safe? (assuming to work with **g++**)
- will it work with any standard optimization? (mainly `-O2`)
- is there a better way to do what I'm doing? (I need to do it to avoid storing *x* and *y* for every `MapBlock` but be able to access them through block without knowing related `MapTile`)
- can I avoid the cast to `u8` when subtracting the offset? I guess no but I just wanted to be sure..

Thanks

Comment: It is most definitely unsafe to whomever tries to read that code.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, since I'm the only one working on the code and if I'm looking for a solution that can save some bytes it means that I really need it, don't you think? :)

Comment: Your `tfb` function clearly assumes that `top` will be the first thing in the structure. Why not go all the way with that, and assume that it's immediately followed by `middle`? Then you could write `(MapTile*)(block - 1)`, which is less future-proof but more clear.

Comment: The `MapTile` struct won't change, so I can definitely do it.. I just thought that I would end up obtaining the same thing since `offsetof` is a macro

Comment: You could make top and middle a two-element array, then the subtract 1 trick would be safe. But I believe your offsetof is fine; you've followed the rules so the compiled must correctly translate it.

Comment: This sounds like microoptimisation. Are you sure that you cannot rearrange your data structure in another way to save more ? (is it sparse ? is there dups ?, is there groups ?)

Comment: It's not sparse, it doesn't have neither dupes nor groups so I'm forced to store all of them individually. But since the map will be really I'm going to save a lot of space if this works seamlessly.

Comment: The code is perfectly understandable as is. It wouldn't hurt to subtract offsetof(struct MapFile, top) in the first case. This should be optimized away when top is the first member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually evertything seemed to work really fine with my solution. The optimizations suggested in comments (using `block - 1`) did work too so feel free to use my example if you have a similar problem!